# Google App Script Notion API Query to Update a Published Task Completion Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, notion-api, notion

Hello and thanks for reading!  I'm working on a small Google Sheet with an Apps Script that runs hourly updating some cells that feed a published chart I use in a notion page.

The cell information is to come from a notion database.

My code is below.  What I'm struggling with is pagination.  The first fetch works as intended for <100 returns but when I go over 100 the behavior I observe is unexpected.  Say for an expected 115x record test the first 100x returns will work but when the second fetch runs I see:

- has_more is still = true (and I'm not anticipating >200 records)
- json.results.length is still 100 (expecting 15)
- When I start indexing over the second fetch I run into a record that didn't match my filter!  That's why I've added protection to drop out.

I'm not sure why this would be.  I'm also not certain if I should be sending the filter as payload on the second fetch.  When I do, I simply get the first 100x over and over again and has_more stays true.  When I have filter in the payload for the first fetch I get the 100x and then I get another 100x of which the first 15x seem correct but then run into an unexpected result.

Any thoughts or ideas appreciated.

Thanks,
-Rich

```
function getNotionTaskCompletions () {
  // Setup URLs 
  const url1 = "https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/xxxxxxx/query/";
  const url2 = "https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/";
  const headers = {
                    Authorization: "Bearer secret_xxxxxxx",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
                  };
  
  // Plan to look for data 30d back
  var nowDate = new Date(Date.now());
  var startDate = new Date(nowDate.getTime() - 30*1000*60*60*24);
  //Logger.log(nowDate);
  //Logger.log(startDate);

  var payld = {
    "filter": {
      "and": [
        {"property": "Status",
         "status": {
           "equals": "Done",
           },
        },        
        {"property": "Complete",
         "date": {
             "on_or_after": startDate,
           },
        },

      ]        
    },
    "sorts": [
      {
        "property": "Complete",
        "direction": "ascending",
      }
    ]
  };

  var tName = [];
  var tDate = [];
  tName.splice(0);
  tDate.splice(0);

  var payload = JSON.stringify(payld);
  var cursor = null;
  var loop = true;
  do {
    var options = {
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "method": "post",
      "headers": headers,
      "start_cursor": cursor,
      "payload": payload,    
    };  
    Logger.log(options);
    var response = undefined;
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
    Logger.log(response);
  
    var json = undefined;
    json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    loop = json.has_more;
    Logger.log(json.results.length + " " + json.has_more);
    for (var j=0; j<json.results.length; ++j) {
      if(json.results[j].properties.Status.status.name != "Done") {
        loop = false
        break;
      }
      Logger.log(j + ": " + json.results[j].properties.Task.title[0].plain_text + " " + json.results[j].properties.Status.status.name);
      Logger.log(j + ": " + json.results[j].properties.Task.title[0].plain_text + " " + json.results[j].properties.Complete.date.start); 
      tName.push(json.results[j].properties.Task.title[0].plain_text);
      tDate.push(json.results[j].properties.Complete.date.start.split("T")[0]);
    }
    payload = null;
    cursor = json.next_cursor;
  } while(loop);

  // Clear out sheet (nice visual that the process in underway)
  var dSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data");
  dSheet.getRange("K1:N300").clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // Put data into spreadsheet to drive chart update
  for (var i=0; i<tName.length; ++i) {
    dSheet.getRange(1+i, 11).setValue(tName[i]);
    dSheet.getRange(1+i, 12).setValue(tDate[i]);          
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading blocks from a page](https://developers.notion.com/reference/working-with-page-content#reading-blocks-from-a-page), it states there that `"Paginated responses are used throughout the Notion API when returning a potentially large list of objects. The maximum number of results in one paginated response is 100."` , This might be the reason why you are having unexpected results.

Comment: The response may contain fewer than page_size of results. If the response includes a next_cursor value, refer to the pagination reference for details about how to use a cursor to iterate through the list.

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far.  So yes, I was aware of the 100 response limit.  What I'm surprised about is when I use the start_cursor feature on my second fetch from the first response I receive 1) more responses than I should in my test case and 2) some of those results do not match the filter in the first fetch.  Does anyone know if I should pass the filter to both the first and subsequent fetches?  When I do I just get the same first 100x responses over and over so I think the answer is no.